# What is the Maximum Merge Articles in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hard limitation for merge replication article count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/hard-limitation-for-merge-replication-article-count)

I am using merge replication in SQL 2012. I am looking here:

- [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server (2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Scroll to the bottom and under the 'Replication Objects' it says that the maximum number of articles in a merge publication is 256.

I wasn't aware of this apparent limitation, but in the mean time I have been running merge replication with 456 articles and everything seems to run fine.

I found these 3 links about it:

- [Too many table names in the query sql 2005 merge replication snapshot error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/f3f505ff-7a62-4131-badb-2ecf58f20808/)
- [FIX: Merge Snapshot Agent Fails with Error 50007: "Too many table names in the query. The maximum allowable is 256."](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296045)
- [Hard limitation for merge replication article count?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/cc17757b-868a-403b-9da7-629597a36286)

So to summarise, apparently in SQL 2000 there was a bug which caused this limit. It was fixed in a service pack, but was reintroduced in SQL 2005.

Does that limitation still exist or not? There doesn't seem to be any official information about SQL 2012.

I would rather management studio tell me 'you cannot add more then 256 articles' rather than having to guess whether this will be a problem for us or not.

Comment: You don't have to break it up into multiple databases, so your foreign keys would be fine. We have run multiple publications for years, putting our lookup tables into one, and our transactional tables into another.

Comment: Just to put it out there. This is not a duplicate based on the fact that the other question has no answer. My answer below proves with reasonable certainty that this limitation does not exist anymore in SQL2012. I don't see anything like this on the other question, it remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced about the publication article limitation of 256. If we look here,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/f3f505ff-7a62-4131-badb-2ecf58f20808/

It is talking about a particular query that causes issues on SQL 2005 when you have more than 256 articles. First I ran the stored procedure sp_MSmakesystableviews.

It then generated a view called MSmerge_cont4F93AE6035D14E46ADA56D87F66E8962_90.

If I take the underlying query in the view it has more than 256 tables. I run that query against a SQL 2005 database and I get the error,

```
Message: Too many table names in the query. The maximum allowable is 256.
```

If I take that same query and run it on SQL 2012 it works fine.

My belief is that the MS documentation is outdated, and unless I find other issues with running merge replication with more than 256 articles I would have to take it that this limitation does not exist anymore from SQL2008 upward.

Answer (score 1):

The first link you provided is official documentation for SQL Server 2012.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

The maximum number of articles supported in Merge Replication is 256.  This means that Microsoft will ensure up to 256 articles will work as expected.  I'm able to exceed 256 articles as well but I wouldn't do it in production.  You may want to consider splitting this up into multiple publications for production purposes.

Comment: But splitting it up is a horrible alternative. That just sounds terrible. How do you deal with foreign keys for instance? Also how do you deal with having two databases at the subscriber end. I mean the client software will have to be changed to deal with this quite majorly. We are upgrading a legacy system.

Comment: Also what will break? Can you give me a specific example so that I can test it?

Comment: Just a quick point, the MSDN documentation gets reused every time, so how do we know that MS could be bothered checking it and updating it properly?

Comment: If certain tables are related or filtered with joins, they'll need to be in the same publication.  This will require multiple subscriptions but it can be done with 1 Subscriber database, so no worries there.

Comment: I cannot say what will break for sure.  Agents would likely fail on sync under certain conditions.

Comment: As far as documentation goes, nothing has changed in this regard so the documentation has not changed either.

Comment: Right. This is not going to work for us because too many tables relate to each other. There is no easy way to split the publication into smaller chunks without breaking referential integrity.

Comment: Are all 256+ articles tables?  I ask, because splitting tables from views, procedures, functions etc. would be one way of splitting up the publications.